# You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next

Tags: next.js, translation

I am trying to add translation to my website by default tutorial,

my /pages/i18n.js

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
// don't want to use this?
// have a look at the Quick start guide 
// for passing in lng and translations on init

i18n
  // load translation using http -> see /public/locales (i.e. https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react/public/locales)
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
  // want your translations to be loaded from a professional CDN? => https://github.com/locize/react-tutorial#step-2---use-the-locize-cdn
  .use(Backend)
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    }
  });


export default i18n;
```

/pages/_document.js

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations'
export default function Document(){
  return(
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <body>
          <Main/>
          <NextScript/>
        </body>
      </Head>
    </Html>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common', 'footer'])),
      // Will be passed to the page component as props
    },
  };
}
```

and navbar with translating string in /component/Navbar.js

```
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';

const Nav = () => {

    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation('navbar');

    
    return (
        <div>
        {t('home')}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Nav;
```

/pages/_app.js

```
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (

  <Component {...pageProps} />

  )
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp);
```

but still translating is not working, I was trying to add async function getStaticProps for translation to Navbar component but there was error "Can't resolve 'fs'" - because you have imported serverSideTranslations in some place where client side code is being run

Comment: this seems to work: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend/tree/master/example/next

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer but hope it helps someone else:

You are getting this error `"Can't resolve 'fs'" - because you have imported serverSideTranslations in some place where client side code is being run` --- because the `getStaticProps`  and `getServerSideProps` should only be used inside the `\pages` directory.

To use the translation outside `\pages` you just need to `import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';` and destructure the `useTranslation()` object `const { t } = useTranslation('navbar');`